# .tfignore files on existing files

Tags: version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I've added a .tfignore file to my solution but it isn't doing anything.
I'm pretty sure my statements in the ignore file are correct but I'm wondering.

- Is it correct to place the file as a solution item or should you have a .tfignore for each project?
- Does .tfignore work with VS 2013?
- Can a .tfignore file handle existing items, because this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.tfignore works with VS2013 however rules only apply to new files.

Existing files that you have already added to source control (or have in your pending changes list) won't suddenly get removed or ignored, because they're already under version control.

The .tfignore file applies to files in the folder it is in, and any subfolders under that.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to make it apply to pending changes?  We've got the packages folder from nuget and it's been in pending changes for a while, but we don't want to add that.  I don't see why the .tfignore shouldn't apply to pending files that you haven't explicitly tried to mark to add.